# CakePHP: Deleting a User deletes Users associated via belongsTo

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I want to be able to delete a User, but a User has a Manager:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
        'Manager' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'manager_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    );
```

And whenever a User is deleted, all of it's "children" are deleted too.

For example, say I delete User A. User A is the manager of users B, C, and D. When A is deleted, so are B, C, and D, because they have A as their `manager_id`.

So my question is - is this supposed to be happening? And is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an ACL issue - totally unexpected. Since our users operate in a tree structure with the Manager, the User has a `lft` and `rght` field that is only updated in the `afterSave`. The easy solution is to dissociate the user by setting their `lft` and `rght` to `0`, but after deeper thought, I am setting their `manager_id` to `NULL` and saving it so that the tree reorganizes itself (via the `afterSave`).

Wow. That was quite the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Read the book, that is intended behavior and you can stop it by adding

```
'dependent' => false,
```

to the associations configuration array.

See http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/view/78/Associations-Linking-Models-Together and search for "dependent" on this page.

And I recommend you to use 2.0 if it's a new project, 1.2 is deprecated for a long time now.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The `dependent` key seems to be only for `hasOne` and `hasMany` relationships, though. This isn't a new project :P I agree though. I'm using 2.1 for my side-project and find myself smiling a lot more.

Comment: Since the case is that delete is meant for hasOne and hasMany, you should rephrase this relation to something else.

hasMany => ManagedUsers .. that should work with burzum's comment